# Why does my reducer isnt updating my store state with ImmutableJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutability

I have this code in my reducer

```
            const copy_states       = fromJS(state);

            const i_copy_jobs        = copy_states.get('calendar_jobs').get(s_from_day_key).get(s_dept_id).get(s_job_id);
            let i_calendar_removed   = copy_states.get('calendar_jobs').deleteIn([s_from_day_key,s_dept_id,s_job_id]);
            const newstate           = copy_states.toJS();

            console.log("BEFORE",state,newstate);

            return newstate;
```

So I am using Immutable.js, what its basically doing is making a copy of state, getting a copied value that will be used later on. Then deleting that value and returning the reduced state.

The log confirms that it indeed removed the value. What I dont understand is, I have a button in the front page to check if the state has changed. When I go and click the button, it saying the state has remained unchanged and so are the other components that's relying on it.

My other reducers works just fine.. Am I missing something on how I use Immutable here?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, when you click the button, the console.log in your reducer confirms the state being updated, but the rendered output doesn't change. Curious. Might need to show the code of the component with the button in it. It could be an issue with the way the components are connected

Comment: @kingdaro The console log in the reducer (from the code) tells me that newstate has removed the value with the "deleteIn" function. So I returned it back to update the store state. All is good but my front page dont see any changes. The button I have for checking the state reveals that my state still is in pre-deleted state thus all my components are unchanged. What could be in between the reducer thats preventing it from updating the state? Thank you for the responsd btw.

Comment: It could be an issue with the way the front page component is connected to redux. Could you show the code for the front page component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your code (after I've refactored)

```
const copiedState = fromJS(state);
const copiedJobs = copiedState.getIn(['calendar_jobs', s_from_day_key, s_dept_id, s_job_id]);
const calendarRemoved = copiedState.deleteIn(['calendar_jobs', s_from_day_key,s_dept_id,s_job_id])
const newState = copiedState.toJS();
return newState;
```

will not result in a different state because any operation on the `copiedState` does not mutate it. Any operation on the immutable object (which is `copiedState` in your case) returns a new object after applying the methods you declared on the immutable. Hence the values in `copiedState` and `newState` will be exactly the same, and that's why you're not seeing the change. i.e Your log `console.log("BEFORE",state,newstate);` should show that they are exactly the same.

So what you want to do instead is:

```
const copiedState = fromJS(state);
const copiedJobs = copiedState.getIn(['calendar_jobs', s_from_day_key, s_dept_id, s_job_id]);
const calendarRemoved = copiedState.deleteIn(['calendar_jobs', s_from_day_key,s_dept_id,s_job_id]);
const newState = calendarRemoved.toJS();
return newState;
```

Comment: Let me refactor the code to this one.  I will let you know. Thank you so much for taking the time. Appreciate it.

Comment: It worked! I was misusing  immutable.js. Any function call must be received into a variable. Simply calling it, and getting the variable itself wont cause any changes. Thank you very much!